# Can I use assist as a synonym of attend?

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to say "I assisted class today" or "the students who ASSISTED class...".  I know that I can use ATTEND. I have looked up ASSIST in the dictionary and it lists ATTEND as a synonym.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not correct.  Attend here means 'to be present at', and that's not what assist means.

Attend has two definitions:

> "I attended class today" = "I was present at class today"

The other definition means to deal with or to look after.

> "The nurse attended to the patient's needs" = "The nurse dealt with
>   the patient's needs"

This can be used as a synonym for assist.  You could also say, "The nurse assisted with the patient's needs."

Comment: Disagree with assist/attend. To attend to a patient's needs is normally used to describe an individual's efforts acting alone. If the nurse was following the direction of another, one would say that he/she "assisted the other in attending to the patient's needs"

Comment: I would say assist and attend can be used interchangeably _in some contexts_.  If you aren't 100% sure, the answer is probably "no".